# The use statement with non-compound name 'yii' has no effect

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, php-7.3

I migrated the old yii2 project to new server which having php 7.3 version. After migrate I got the issue while rendering view from controller near

```
use yii;
use DateTime;
```

Comment: [Check out the mistake and solution in this issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6897)

Comment: Could you try it again by typing it correctly (case sensitive): 
use Yii;

Comment: Hey, I just changed my php version from 7.3 to 7.4 and it is running now